# Illustrator diagonal lines into straight lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, shapes, line-art, anchor-point

I have these diagonal lines in my artboard which I want to make vertical lines.

The horizonal lines are easy to make vertical but how can I make the diagonal lines also vertical?

I tried several options but failed, there seems no other topic on here which solves my problem.

Hope there is someone with the knowledge!

[image: Diagonal lines into straight lines]

**EDIT:**
What I actually mean is this line down here is a diagonal. I want this to be rotated so it gets a straight line (horizontal or vertical).
[image]

Comment: ermm.. huh? You can't align the anchors?

Comment: Do you mean to *rotate* the M so one of the diagonal lines are vertical (and all the other lines are then diagonal)? Or do you perhaps mean that you want the diagonal lines to be *parallel* (not *vertical*)?

Comment: I added some drawing in the post to make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(updated answer after seeing your question edit)*

There's an easy way to rotate one end of a line, while the other end stays in place:

- make sure you have `Smart guides` turned on
- create a vertical guideline touching one of the anchors
- hit <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate and click that very same anchor point (mouse cursor will change). This will make the line rotate around that point (locks the point in place).
- grab the other anchor point and move it towards the guideline until it snaps
- release

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the path you wish to make vertical is part of a larger path, you can align anchors. **This only works if *all* anchors on path are *not* selected.**

- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow)
- Select the top anchor and the bottom anchor
- Click the vertical align options in the **Align Panel**

Anchors can be aligned if they are individually selected.

[image]

---

If you aren't concerned with maintaining any specific anchor position, you can use **average**

- Select the path
- Choose `Object > Path > Average`
- Tick `Vertical` and hit `OK`

[image]

This averages the two anchors, aligning them vertically essentially in the middle of where the two anchors started. Sort of the same as "align on center".

---

If your path consists of *only* two anchors, **and** you want to **maintain the existing position** of one of the anchors.... see @Lucian's rotate method.